# Not able to access variables in jest.mock function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Please check below scenario

```
const url = 'https://mock.com/mockpath';
jest.mock('../../src/somefile', () => {
  return ({
    getURL: jest.fn(() => url),
  });
});
```

I am getting error

```
babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
Invalid variable access: url
```

Comment: what version do you use? is it very top of your test? variables with name started with [`mock` should be allowed](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't have mock in front of my variable. Just added mock and problem solved.

Comment: All praise @skyboyer !!  Seriously, thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Courtesy [@skyboyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071697/skyboyer)

Just renamed url to mockUrl, any variable starting with mock is accessible inside jest.mock.

[@skyboyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071697/skyboyer) thanks again for the help.

Comment: btw, you still can provide different values for dependant variable per each test case(it barely makes sense for base URL but may be useful in other cases). All you need is making sure both `jest.mock` and test case are accessing referentially same variable

Comment: `let mockSmth = { value: 5 }; jest.mock(.... mockSmt.value ... ); .... it(.... mockSmth.value = 5; ...` - notice variable `mockSmth` is _referentially_ the same all the time

Comment: I worship thee from a remote chair at a big tech co.  You just saved me hours!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
'jest.mock()' is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: mockURL
```

It's telling you that `jest.mock()` is trying to access `mockURL`, but it is not allowed to access an out-of-scope variable.

You should declare `mockURL` inside the `jest.mock()` function call:

```
jest.mock('../../src/somefile', () => {
  const mockURL = 'https://mock.com/mockpath';
  return ({
    getURL: jest.fn(() => mockURL),
  });
});
```

Or you could just reference the string without using the intermediate variable:

```
jest.mock('../../src/somefile', () => ({
  getURL: jest.fn(() => 'https://mock.com/mockpath'),
}));
```

Comment: To avoid code redundancy I need the variable out of jest.mock as later I am using the variable

Comment: You can't do it. If you use a variable inside `jest.mock` you must declare it inside `jest.mock`. See [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2567) for an explanation.