# React IonDateTime does not render in Jest test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, jestjs

When running Jest on an Ionic React component, the following test fails, regardless of whether or not the component receives a time value.

```
test('IonDateTime appears', () => {
  render(<IonDatetime data-testid="foo" mode="ios" />);
  const dateTimeComponent = screen.getByTestId('foo');

  expect(dateTimeComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This is the output from Jest, where the body comes back with an empty div.

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="foo"]
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>
```

I have `mockIonicReact();` in my setupTests.ts file, which should allow for different Ionic components to get rendered in JSDOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside mockIonicReact.js, Jest can't use the mockController unless the variable to which it is assigned also begins with the word "mock"
Previously answered at:

- [Jest Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665358/not-able-to-access-variables-in-jest-mock-function)

As of 16 Jun 2021, still a bug in Ionic React ([view here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-react-test-utils/issues/18))